# Lamp server not showing file without extension

Tags: virtualhost, lamp

I am getting a weird issue i created a vhost in lamp stack. The problem is that when I open the vhost site www.domain.com the home page loads without any issue.

But when I use the nav bar to open another page I get a "404 NOT FOUND" i.e www.domain.com/about

But as soon as I put the extension of the file manually the page loads.
www.domain.com/about.php

How can I solve this issue. I am using .htaccess to hide the extension of the file.

Note:
1) All the other local file running properly i.e. I have a wordpress site that works fine (This means the mysql db is not causing the error)

2) The vhost is set properly bcus the terminal did not show any error when the vhost was enabled.

But the vhost in wamp does not give me any kind of issue in my windows 8.1 pro.

Edit :
Code in .htaccess to hide extension this works in my windows pc without any problem.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

EDIT -2

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory /var/www/stab-website>

        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all

    </Directory>

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/stab-website"
    ServerName stab-site.com

    ServerAlias  www.stab-site.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Still did not worked.

Comment: Would be nice if you added your virtual host configuration to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thanks @Cyclone for your help**

This post helped me to fix this issue
https://askubuntu.com/questions/233046/how-to-give-my-user-permission-to-add-edit-files-on-local-apache-server

The post above help to run Apache server as the logged in user.

**To give rights to use .htaccess --**

First, you should ensure that your username is included in www-data group. If not, you can add your username as www-data group

```
sudo adduser $USER www-data
```

After that, you should change the ownership of /var/www to your username

```
sudo chown $USER:www-data -R /var/wwws
```

**And also don't forget to add this code in the apache2.conf**

`<Directory /var/www/ProjectRootDirectory>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the `MultiViews` options:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  <Directory /var/www/htdocs>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  </Directory>

  ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/htdocs"
  ServerName dummy-host.example.com
  ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

This can either be done in your `httpd.conf` file, in the configuration file for your virtual host or in a `.htaccess` file.

You should also make sure so that the `mod_negotiation` module is enabled. This can be done by running:

```
sudo a2enmod negotiation
```

You also might need to verify that your virtual host configuration is fine, this can be done from the terminal using:

```
apache2ctl -t
```

After this you need to restart your server:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

From the [`documentation`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html):

> The effect of MultiViews is as follows: if the server receives a
>   request for /some/dir/foo, if /some/dir has MultiViews enabled, and
>   /some/dir/foo does not exist, then the server reads the directory
>   looking for files named foo.*, and effectively fakes up a type map
>   which names all those files, assigning them the same media types and
>   content-encodings it would have if the client had asked for one of
>   them by name. It then chooses the best match to the client's
>   requirements.

Comment: @RajendranNadar - Yes, you should be able to add this inside your vhost file or as I said above you could also add it in an `.htaccess` file - **notice** that this directive must be inside a `<Directory ...>` block.

Comment: Nope did not worked for me.. The directory is opening but the .php files give error

Comment: @RajendranNadar - Have you restarted your server? Also, make sure so that `mod_negotiation` module is enabled i.e: `sudo a2enmod negotiation`

Comment: yup, using the terminal

Comment: @RajendranNadar - And you checked so that the `mod_negotiation` module is enabled? Running `sudo a2enmod negotiation`

Comment: @RajendranNadar - Okej, then I think you must have done something wrong in your configuration. Edit your question and show how you're hiding the fileextension using `.htaccess`? This might be the problem. You also can check your virtual host configuration by running `apache2ctl -t`

Comment: sudo apache2ctl -t gives Syntax ok

Comment: @RajendranNadar - I edited the above and it worked fine for me as long as I also added `FollowSymLinks` to options.

Comment: Did you try this in LAMP because every thing works fine in my WAMP

Comment: Yes I'm running a LAMP server.

Comment: Do i need to give any special rights to my .htaccess because even this is not working `RewriteRule about about.php` and my wordpress installation works very well.

Comment: @RajendranNadar - You might need to set `AllowOverride All` in your `Directory` configuration to allow `.htaccess` overrides.